# Add youtube video to google document - is it possible? Through Apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Is it possible to insert YouTube video into [google document](http://docs.google.com/document/):

1. Manually (it must be video, not a link in text)
2. By Apps Script

I didn't find any method to insert video in document like inserting Images or insert/appendParagraph etc, so nothing to add. No code for that.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts and a code snippet that show what you tried. Reference [ask].

Comment: I didn't find any method to insert video in document like inserting Images or insert/appendParagraph etc, so nothing to add. No code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely post it into the sidebar of a Google Doc. I know it's a trivial simple answer but it is possible.  I'm listening to it right now.

```
 //Here is the code.gs code:
    function onOpen() {
      var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
      ui.createMenu('My Handler Tools')
          .addItem('Show SideBar3','SideBar3')
          .addSeparator()
          .addToUi();
    };

    function SideBar3()
    {
      var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ModeLessDialog').setTitle('Handler Communications');
      DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
    }

    //Here is the HTML file.  I called it ModeLessDialog.html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
      </head>
      <body>
      <iframe width="200" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xsu2AUxcH4k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

      </body>
    </html>
```

This code was written in Google Docs Script Editor.

Comment: Thanx, Cooper. But it's not what i try to do. I'm searching solutions how to add video not to sidebar/addon or elsewhere but inside document. And my research last week didn't give me anything about it. So i started to think that it's impossible by Apps Script at all. By other google apps - yes, by adding addon panel/sidebar - yes. But as google document inline video - no. No full support of regexp, no inline video, no other things... Ok, i must take it. Thanx for your answer.

Comment: I have a crazy idea - what if we download as .html, unzip, parse it, add inline iframe, zip, and upload. What Google Document will show? Really crazy. I must try it (it will break versioning and history, but to know what will happens i must try this crazy idea).

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think it's possible in to insert a video into the google document except for a sidebar or dialog. I would recommend that you consider taking a look at the new google sites.  They are very easy to use and adding video is one of their builtin features.  There's no need for coding  and you can provide users with a URL to access the pages from any website.  I use them on my website because they're easy to use and they format the pages pretty well so that they fit on any device. Here's the [link](https://sites.google.com/new?usp=jotspot_si)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible through appscript.
Please refer below code to achieve the same. Here I have set an image with a youtube link and set the image width as "0" so in this, the video is not visible however you do get a thumbnail of youtube video which can be played in the same window.

```
<i></i>
<div style="font-size: 12px;" align="left">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7Kcs9OD5wk" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> <img style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; clear: both; border: 0px; height: auto; line-height: 100%; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 3px; margin-bottom: 0px; float: left; max-width: 0px; width: 100% !important;" title="Image" src="https://i.postimg.cc/qRrvx6pX/Fostercraftvideo.jpg"
      alt="Image" width="0" align="left" border="0" /> </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Google Docs I don't think it's possible. I'd recommend you to use Google Sites.

Using Apps Script it's possible and pretty easy. You'll need to create a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) that shows a html file using a [HtmlService API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service), then you can edit your html file normally and embed your video.

Comment: Not so clear for me (i'm new to Apps Script). Read Web App and HtmlService API pages and didn't understand how to embed video (youtube for example) into a google document.
Maybe i misunderstood your answer...

Comment: Maycow: Why do you recommend to use Google Sites? Did you already tried as a word processor?

Comment: It's possible with Google Docs script editor, see Cooper's post